# android GcmIntentService not able to get new message from server

Tags: android, message, google-cloud-messaging

In one of my application i need to make app like chat application in that i am able to send data from device to server but not able to get data back from server to device.

In my manifest file... i have done

```
<permission android:name="<package name>.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
            android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="<package name>.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" /> 

    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<receiver
    android:name="<package name>.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <category android:name="<package name>" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

<service android:name=".GcmIntentService" ></service>
```

my GcmIntentService is like

```
public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService {

    private static final String TAG = "GcmIntentService";

    public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 101;
    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;

    private DBAdapter dbAdapter;

    public GcmIntentService() {
        super(TAG);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        System.out.println("GcmIntentService>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");// this tag display in logcat
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
        String gcmMessageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

        if (!extras.isEmpty()) {
            // has effect of unparcelling Bundle
            if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR
                    .equals(gcmMessageType)) {
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED
                    .equals(gcmMessageType)) {
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE
                    .equals(gcmMessageType)) {

                AppLog.Log(TAG, "newMessage :: " + intent);

                String newMessage = intent.getExtras().getString("message");

                AppLog.Log(TAG, "newMessage :: " + newMessage);

                try {
                    handleMessage(newMessage);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        // Release the wake lock provided by the WakefulBroadcastReceiver.
        GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }

    private void handleMessage(String message) throws JSONException {

        if (message == null) {
            return;
        }

        dbAdapter = new DBAdapter(getApplicationContext());

        UserDetail detail = new MyPrefrence(getApplicationContext())
                .getDetail();

        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(message);
        object = object.getJSONObject("details");
        int who = object.getInt("who");

        switch (who) {
        case MessageModel.WHO_PERSONAL:
            AHttpResponse response = new AHttpResponse(message, true);
            MessageModel model = response.getSendMessage();

            insertIfUSerNotExits(model, message);

            model.setMessageStatus(MessageModel.STATUS_DELIVERED);
            String tempMessage = null;
            AppLog.Log(TAG, "MESSAGE ::" + model);

            switch (model.getMessageType()) {
            case MessageModel.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE:
                tempMessage = model.getDisplayName() + ":" + model.getMessage();
                break;

            case MessageModel.MESSAGE_TYPE_VEDIO:
                tempMessage = model.getDisplayName() + ": Video";
                break;

            case MessageModel.MESSAGE_TYPE_IMAGE:
                tempMessage = model.getDisplayName() + ": image";
                break;

            case MessageModel.MESSAGE_TYPE_LOCATION:
                tempMessage = model.getDisplayName() + ": location";
                break;

            case MessageModel.MESSAGE_TYPE_CONTACT:
                tempMessage = model.getDisplayName() + " sends you contact of "
                        + model.getMessage().split("//s+")[0];
                break;

            }
            if (message != null) {
                generateNotification(tempMessage);
            }

            dbAdapter.openForWrite();
            int receiveMessageID = dbAdapter.insertMessage(model);
            int userUpdateId = dbAdapter.updateLastMessageId(
                    receiveMessageID,
                    detail.getUserId() == model.getUserID() ? model
                            .getFriendId() : model.getUserID());
            if (userUpdateId == 1) {
                AppLog.Log(TAG, "User Update Success");
            } else {
                AppLog.Log(TAG, "User Update UnSucess");
            }
            dbAdapter.close();

            // Intent intent = new Intent(MyActions.MESSAGE_UPDATE);
            // LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext())
            // .sendBroadcast(intent);
            break;
        case MessageModel.WHO_GROUP:

            AppLog.Log(TAG,
                    "******************Group Message Received*********************");

            AHttpResponse responseG = new AHttpResponse(message, true);
            MessageModel modelG = responseG.getSendMessage();

            insertIfUSerNotExits(modelG, message);

            modelG.setMessageStatus(MessageModel.STATUS_DELIVERED);
            AppLog.Log(TAG, "MESSAGE ::" + modelG);
            // modelG.setUserID(new MyPrefrence(this).getDetail().getUserId());
            // generateNotification(model.getDisplayName() + ":"
            // + model.getMessage());
            dbAdapter.openForWrite();
            int receiveMessageIDG = dbAdapter.insertMessage(modelG);
            if (modelG.getMessage() != null) {
                generateNotification(modelG.getMessage());
            }
            int userUpdateIdG = dbAdapter.updateLastMessageId(
                    receiveMessageIDG,
                    detail.getUserId() == modelG.getUserID() ? modelG
                            .getFriendId() : modelG.getUserID());
            if (userUpdateIdG == 1) {
                AppLog.Log(TAG, "User Update Success");
            } else {
                AppLog.Log(TAG, "User Update UnSucess");
            }
            dbAdapter.close();
            break;

        case MessageModel.WHO_JOIN_GROUP:
            AHttpResponse aHttpResponse = new AHttpResponse(message, true);
            UserDetail userDetail = aHttpResponse.getJoinGroupDetail();
            AppLog.Log(TAG, "userdetail :: " + userDetail.getName());

            dbAdapter.openForRead();
            dbAdapter.insertOrUpdateGroup(userDetail);
            AppLog.Log(TAG, "Group is Created ");

            getGtoupDetailFromServer(userDetail);
            // } else {
            // AppLog.Log(TAG, "Group creation failed");
            // }
            dbAdapter.close();

            // dbAdapter.inserGroup();
            // {"details":{"id":"119","time":"2014-06-12 17:02:11","type":"","user_id":"131","friend_id":"","who":"4","message":"","delivery_time":"","image":"group\/default.jpg","user_status":"","phone":"","phone_code":"","name":"test
            // 33","status":""},"success":true,"message":"Successfully group
            // created."}

            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

        Intent intent = new Intent(MyActions.MESSAGE_UPDATE);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext())
                .sendBroadcast(intent);

    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param model
     * @param newMessage
     * 
     *            responsible if user does not exists in database
     */
    private void insertIfUSerNotExits(MessageModel model, String newMessage) {

        dbAdapter.openForRead();
        UserDetail userDetail = dbAdapter.getUserDetail(model.getUserID());
        dbAdapter.close();
        if (userDetail == null) {
            UserDetail newUserDetail = new UserDetail();
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(newMessage);
                if (jsonObject.has("details")) {
                    jsonObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("details");

                    newUserDetail.setUserId(jsonObject.getInt("user_id"));
                    newUserDetail.setImage(jsonObject.getString("image"));
                    newUserDetail
                            .setStatus(jsonObject.getString("user_status"));
                    newUserDetail.setPhoneNo(jsonObject.getString("phone"));
                    newUserDetail.setPhoneCode(jsonObject
                            .getString("phone_code"));
                    newUserDetail.setName(jsonObject.getString("name"));
                    // time to insert local database
                    dbAdapter.openForRead();
                    dbAdapter.insertOrUpdateUser(newUserDetail);
                    dbAdapter.close();

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }

    private void getGtoupDetailFromServer(final UserDetail detail) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", detail
                        .getUserId() + ""));
                HttpRequest httpRequest = new HttpRequest();
                try {
                    String responseString = httpRequest.postData(
                            Urls.GET_GROUP_MEMBER, nameValuePairs);
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(responseString);
                    AppLog.Log(TAG, "Getting Group Detail response :: "
                            + responseString);
                    if (jsonObject.getBoolean("success")) {
                        JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("details");
                        dbAdapter.openForWrite();
                        dbAdapter.deleteAllGroupUsers(detail.getUserId());
                        dbAdapter.close();

                        AppLog.Log(TAG, "GRoup Members ***************** "
                                + array.length());
                        UserDetail detail;
                        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                            detail = new UserDetail();
                            jsonObject = array.getJSONObject(i);
                            detail.setUserId(jsonObject.getInt("id"));
                            detail.setGroupId(jsonObject.getInt("group_id"));
                            detail.setAdmin(jsonObject.getInt("is_admin") == 1);
                            detail.setName(jsonObject.getString("name"));
                            detail.setPhoneCode(jsonObject
                                    .getString("phone_code"));
                            detail.setPhoneNo(jsonObject.getString("phone"));
                            detail.setImage(jsonObject.getString("image"));
                            detail.setStatus(jsonObject.getString("status"));
                            dbAdapter.openForRead();

                            dbAdapter.insertUpdateGroupMember(detail);
                            dbAdapter.close();
                        }
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();

    }

    private void generateNotification(String message) {
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setStyle(
                        new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(message))
                .setTicker(message).setContentText(message).setAutoCancel(true);

        // Play default notification sound
        mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND
                | Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL);

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                new Intent(this, RecentChatList.class), 0);

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
    }
```

and GcmBroadcastReceiver class

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    // private static final String TAG = "GcmBroadcastReceiver";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Explicitly specify that GcmIntentService will handle the intent.
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                GcmIntentService.class.getName());
        System.out.println("PACKAGE NAME>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"+context.getPackageName()+"");
        System.out.println("GcmBroadcastReceiver>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");////still running
        // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
        System.out.println("GcmBroadcastReceiver STARTED>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");//still running

        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);

    }
```

*note GcmIntentService and GcmBroadcastReceiver is lies under my direct package

Please help to sove this problem

Answer (score 1):

You need this permission to receive messages:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
```

To register,

```
GoogleCloudMessaging mGCM = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(mContext);
String regId = mGCM.register(GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID);
```

Then just check if regId is a valid String.

Comment: have given that permission also

Comment: Well it is not included in your snippet. Were you able to get a regId using GoogleCloudMessaging.register()?

Comment: how to check that please help i am new to GCM

Comment: not able to see but i am able to send data to server

Comment: hello yes i am getting key that is quit big

Comment: hello my server is not dedicated server... can be it create problem?